VBA Loop does not loop
I am working on a loop to look through the export file sheet column AF, which is column 32; if a cell in column 32 equals #N/A, then copy the value in column AE, which is column 31, and paste in sheet 'errors and resolutions' column A last row. My loop breaks at the next loop on the if statement line.
    'Loop through column AF
    For i = 2 To last row
    
    'Activate worksheet
    Worksheets("Exported File").Activate
    
    'If condition is met then copy value from column AE
        If ws.Cells(i, 32).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then ws.Cells(i, 31).Copy Else 'do nothing
    '
            'Activate Errors & Resolutions sheet
            Worksheets("Errors & Resolutions").Activate
            
            'Find next empty cell
            Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select

           'Paste values123 (Actual values)
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

'
        End If
'
    Next i


For i = 2 To last row how is last row declared and assigned a value?

Side note: in general, it's a good idea to avoid  using Select in your code

The structure of this loop is invalid. It should be:
If  Then    Else   End If. Other than that, I think copy and paste should be at the same value of i.

Range("A1").End(xlDown) if A2 is empty, this will go to the end of the sheet and Offset(1) will send it off the sheet which will cause it to error.

@ScottCraner can you point me to how to declare or assign a value to last row, will that be last row = Range("AF1:AF")?

@cybernetic.nomad what will be the select replacement please?

@ScottCraner for the "If A2 is empty..." so what i was trying to do is to capture the next empty cell in that column to paste the value i copied from the other sheet. What would be the best syntax for this line if you don't mind?.

@MGonet that was how i initially wrote it, i found a training that says, you can put your if statement in a single line.

Yes, you can, but then everything from If, Then and possibly Else must be in this single line. If this line you wrote was a single-line If instruction then a few lines below  is End If without If.

@dreh84 I provided a link in my previous comment...

Copy Matching Values
For...Next
Sub CopyValuesFor()

    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Export File")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Errors & Resolutions")
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim sValue As Variant, i As Long
 
    ' Loop through the rows of the source sheet.
    For i = 2 To slRow
        sValue = sws.Cells(i, "AF").Value
        ' Comparing an error value with a non-error value will result
        ' in a type mismatch error. Therefore make sure you compare
        ' only errors with errors:
        If IsError(sValue) Then ' the value in column 'AF' is an error
            ' Only if the error is a Not-Available error,...
            If sValue = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
                ' ... reference the next destination cell...
                Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1)
                ' ... and write the corresponding value from column 'AE' to it.
                dcell.Value = sws.Cells(i, "AE").Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Values copied.", vbInformation

End Sub


For Each...Next
Sub CopyValuesForEach()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Export File")
    
    Dim slrg As Range:
    Set slrg = sws.Range("AF2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp))
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns("AE")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Errors & Resolutions")
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

    Dim scell As Range, sValue As Variant, sRow As Long, dRow As Long
 
    For Each scell In slrg.Cells
        sRow = sRow + 1
        sValue = scell.Value
        If IsError(sValue) Then ' is an error
            If sValue = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then ' is a #N/A error
                dRow = dRow + 1
                dcell.Offset(dRow).Value = srrg.Cells(sRow).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next scell

    MsgBox "Out of " & sRow & " cell" & IIf(sRow = 1, "", "s") & " in ""'" _
        & sws.Name & "'!" & srrg.Address(0, 0) & """, " & dRow _
        & " had ""#N/A"" in the corresponding cell" _
        & IIf(dRow = 1, "", "s") & " of ""'" _
        & sws.Name & "'!" & slrg.Address(0, 0) & """ and " _
        & IIf(dRow = 1, "was", "were") & " copied to ""'" _
        & dws.Name & "'!" & dcell.Offset(1).Resize(dRow).Address(0, 0) _
        & """.", vbInformation

End Sub

